# How to add condition before reboot Linux machine

Tags: linux, bash, alias, redhat

We want to add some important test before init 6 will take effect  ( on redhat )

As the following

We add the function ( init )  in /root/.bashrc

```
init () {
    /home/sanity.sh
    [[ $? –eq 0 ]] && echo "reboot will performed" || 
         echo "reboot will not performed because sanity.sh exit with error" && exit 1
    Sleep 1
    init $@    
}
```

But from some unclear reason **init 6** not performed

What is wrong in my function?

Goal – before **init 6** command , we want to get status from   **/home/sanity.sh**
 Script

If status is 0 then **init 6** will done , if not then init 6 will not allowed !

Comment: this function loops infinitely, how do you know it's not called

Comment: function was called but reboot not done , so something in the middle not as expected

Comment: `init ()` -> Why not put a more sensible name for the function ? This would conflict with the `init` - the service manager. As a side note double-quote `$@`.

Comment: because user need to use "init 6" command , and when we use init the function init will take action instead the real init CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your test is re-written to print what it does, rather than do it, firstly passing:

```
~$> x=0
~$> [[ $x -eq 0 ]] && echo "pass1" || echo "fail1" && echo "exit"
pass1
exit
```

Then failing:

```
~$> x=1
~$> [[ $x -eq 0 ]] && echo "pass1" || echo "fail1" && echo "exit"
fail1
exit
```

so you need to group everything after the `||` so the `exit` is only performed if `test` fails:

```
~$> x=0
~$> [[ $x -eq 0 ]] && echo "pass1" || { echo "fail1" && echo "exit"; }
pass1
```

Then you will need to use `command` to actually call `init`:

> The command utility shall cause the shell to treat the arguments  as  a simple command, suppressing the shell function lookup that is described in Section 2.9.1.1, Command Search and Execution, item 1b.